# Windows Phone - How do I get the HTTP Status Code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I had to manually wire-up my networking layer. To run a query against a web service, I'm using the following code:

```
public void RunService()
{
  string serviceUrl = Constants.URL_OF_SERVICE;
  WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
  request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(Service_Completed), request);
}

private void Service_Completed(IAsyncResult result)
{
  try
  {
    WebRequest request = (WebRequest)(result.AsyncState);
    WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);

    // Continue doing stuff
  }
  catch (WebException ex1)
  {
    // How do I get the HTTP Status code here?
  }
}
```

I'm having problems getting the HTTP Status Code when an error happens. Can somebody please tell me how to get the HTTP Status code when a WebException is thrown?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `WebResponse` which is [part of the `WebException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx):

```
catch (WebException ex1)
{
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) ex1.Response)
    {
        if (response == null)
        {
            // Whatever
        }
        else
        {
            HttpStatusCode status = response.StatusCode;
            // Whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Windows Phone is that ANY error is translated into "404 not found" - even if there is simply no network or server does not respond at all, you will still get "404" - which is absurd and obviously a bug.

Comment: You need to check the `ResponseUri` property. If it's empty then you can deduct that it's not a real 404, but a communication problem. This is only partial solution: you still won't be able to tell apart real 404 from other 4XX or 5XX.